# Can not set up Xdebug for any IDE using Laradock + PHP 7.2 + PhpStorm/VSCode + Xdebug 2.9.8/Xdebug 3.0.3 working with Laravel project from WSL

Tags: php, docker, laravel-5, visual-studio-code, phpstorm

I have a big issue for setting up Xdebug in my Laravel project + Laradock.
I have tried with PhpStorm and also with VSCode.

I also have tried using Xdebug 3, writing the same settings on both xdebug.ini but with the new Xdebug3 sentences.

Maybe should I have to set up something else inside WSL ?

I have tried with a lot of combinations on my xdebug.ini but without success.

Below my configurations file:

**php-fpm/xdebug.ini**

```
xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp/profiling"

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```

**php-workspace/xdebug.ini**

```
xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp/profiling"

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```

**LARADOCK FOLDER**

```
...
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG=true
...
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG=true
...
# Create an account on blackfire.io. Don't enable blackfire and xDebug at the same time. # visit https://blackfire.io/docs/24-days/06-installation#install-probe-debian for more info.
INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=false
```

**LARADOCK/PHP-FPM/Dockerfile**

```
###########################################################################
# xDebug:
###########################################################################

ARG INSTALL_XDEBUG=false

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; then \
  # Install the xdebug extension
  if [ $(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION;") = "5" ]; then \
    pecl install xdebug-2.5.5; \
  else \
    if [ $(php -r "echo PHP_MINOR_VERSION;") = "0" ]; then \
      pecl install xdebug-2.9.0; \
    else \
      pecl install xdebug-2.9.8; \
    fi \
  fi && \
  docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
;fi

# Copy xdebug configuration for remote debugging
COPY ./xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

RUN sed -i "s/xdebug.remote_autostart=0/xdebug.remote_autostart=1/" /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini && \
    sed -i "s/xdebug.remote_enable=0/xdebug.remote_enable=1/" /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini && \
    sed -i "s/xdebug.cli_color=0/xdebug.cli_color=1/" /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

**LARADOCK/WORKSPACE/Dockerfile**

```
###########################################################################
# xDebug:
###########################################################################

USER root

ARG INSTALL_XDEBUG=false

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; then \
  # Install the xdebug extension
  if [ $(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION;") = "5" ]; then \
    pecl install xdebug-2.5.5; \
  else \
    if [ $(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION;") = "7" ] && [ $(php -r "echo PHP_MINOR_VERSION;") = "0" ]; then \
      pecl install xdebug-2.9.0; \
    else \
      if [ $(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION;") = "7" ] && [ $(php -r "echo PHP_MINOR_VERSION;") = "1" ]; then \
        pecl install xdebug-2.9.8; \
      else \
        if [ $(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION;") = "7" ]; then \
          pecl install xdebug-2.9.8; \
        else \
          #pecl install xdebug; \
          echo "xDebug 3 required, not supported."; \
        fi \
      fi \
    fi \
  fi && \
  echo "zend_extension=xdebug.so" >> /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini \
;fi

# ADD for REMOTE debugging
COPY ./xdebug.ini /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini

RUN sed -i "s/xdebug.remote_autostart=0/xdebug.remote_autostart=1/" /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini && \
    sed -i "s/xdebug.remote_enable=0/xdebug.remote_enable=1/" /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini && \
    sed -i "s/xdebug.cli_color=0/xdebug.cli_color=1/" /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

**laradock/docker-compose.yml**

```
### Workspace Utilities ##################################
    workspace:
      build:
        context: ./workspace
        args:
           ...
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          ...
### PHP-FPM ##############################################
    php-fpm:
      build:
        context: ./php-fpm
        args:
          ...
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          ...
```

**PHPSTORM SETTINGS**
[image]
[image]

**WINDOWS SETTINGS**

[image]

[image]

**PHPINFO()**

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) Enable and collect Xdebug log and see what it has to say -- you should always start there to see what is actually happening (if Xdebug is even trying to connect anywhere or not) 2) Since Xdebug v3 is out and v2 is no longer supported + standard 9000 port may conflict with php-fpm -- it makes perfect sense to either use 9003 or at least 9001 (or alike) instead of default 9000 (regardless of your Xdebug version).

Comment: 3) Ensure that PhpStorm (or VSCode) is actually listening for Xdebug connections on that port (e.g. when "phone handle" icon is green in PhpStorm) 4)Windows Firewall: I would just grant "ALL" access to PhpStorm on ALL profiles and not just selected -- will not hurt. 5) https://learnxdebug.com/

Comment: I had you same exact problem, and this helped me a lot: https://medium.com/@tomasbruckner/intellij-xdebug-with-wsl-2-docker-4224b6efb0bb. The main point is where it writes about `Hurdle #3`.